# Do I need to use a database for a simple python script?

Tags: python, database

I'm building my first web app (hooray!). It's a very basic app that will take form input and spit it out in a script file for copying and pasting. I'm new to this all - do I need a database for something this simple? Building it in Flask, but I know enough Javascript to use that as well.

I played around with LocalStorage for a similar project, but have read that it can be a security risk. I've done some tutorials that have used SQLAlchemy and SQLite, but even those seem unnecessary for something this small.

Really appreciate any help on this - excited to get this sorted out!

Comment: what have you done yet? Can you please show some of your code?

Comment: @kyledeanreinford that's great!  Programming is really fun.  You should checkout https://www.pythonanywhere.com/ it's a great tool for hosting simple web apps (use the free version).  You'll also probably want to develop in something like weight like visual studio code.  Note, this is not the same as visual studio.  BTW, you don't need a DB for your project.

Comment: @MatthewE.Miller Thanks! Will check that out. I've been using Atom - is VSC better for some reason?

Comment: @kyledeanreinford not sure about better/worse, it's just preference.  VS Code has a lot of extensions, documentation, and other helpful features.  It's a good lightweight editor for web programming.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are trying to store anything in the DB you don't any database connection. You are just taking input from a form and saving the same info in a script file or a text file. Database does not come into picture at all.

Comment: Great - thank you for taking the time to answer this!